# I want to create html page for salesforce community login? How to do that?

Tags: javascript, community, site.com

Hi i want to create html page for salesforce community login. I wanted to provide login to community user through site.com. For which i want to create custom HTML page which will take username and password and after logging in it will show salesforce community. I have read communities implementation guide and currently I tried to do this functionality with the help of VF page and apex controller. But as i wanted to use this page in site.com and site.com doesn't support VF page so,instead of that i want to create HTML page which will do this kind of functionality(validation,authentication and login from that page).I checked various sites, but couldn't find the solution. So what should i do to solve my problem?

Comment: If you include more details about what you have tried and where you are getting stuck, it will better help us answer your question.

Comment: hello martin, actually i am new to salesforce. I dont have any idea of how to do this. so posted this question.Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: See [Getting Started with Communities](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf). All developer documentation and workbooks needed to learn the Salesforce environment can be found from [Developer Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs?utf8=%E2%9C%93&select_subject%5B%5D=Force.com&select_type=&filter_text=&commit=FILTER+RESULTS).

Comment: gusy it wont help much. i want to create html page for salesforce community login and Community doccumnets on salesforce site wont specify that information. Please, if anyone know how to do it then put your solution here!

Comment: Hello, as my problem is not concerned with customizing communities login page, It is concerned with performing authentication, validation and login functionality to salesforce communities via basic html/javascript page.So i think my question should be reopened.Thank you.